# Error with deploy Chatwoot in Heroku: Free dynos are no longer available

Tags: heroku, chatwoot

The following error appears, but I am already subscribed to an Eco subscription:

> Run scripts & scale dynos
> Error scaling dynos: Free dynos are no longer available. Subscribe to Eco to get your app running. Learn more at https://blog.heroku.com/new-low-cost-plans

Deploy my app on Heroku

Comment: Did you [change the dynos for your app to be eco dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#setting-dyno-types)?

Comment: @Chris When I tried to do what you asked, this appeared: "This app has no process types yet Add a Procfile to your app in order to define its process types. Learn more"

Comment: I don't know anything about Chatwoot, but [it looks like they ship a `Procfile` in the source code](https://github.com/chatwoot/chatwoot/blob/develop/Procfile). Are you sure you've deployed your code correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Chatwoot v2.12.0 contains an updated Procfile which uses `basic` dynos instead of `FREE` ones. Deploying the newer version should fix the error for you.

ref: https://github.com/chatwoot/chatwoot/pull/5349